# how to use multiple subdomain for multiple states in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Property website that is build in WordPress.

Now I want to show the properties according to the states and when user select any state from the given list and click on submit then the URL should be shown as a sub-domain like in **"olx.in"**(jaipur.olx.in and pune.olx.in etc).

The main site should be the same for example the main site is mysite.com and the state wise subdomain should be abc.mysite.com, xyz.mysite.com etc.

abc.mysite.com and xyz.mysite.com should should show be the main site only, only the URL will be changed according to the selected state from a given drop-down list.

I want show the property list according to the state given in the URL.

I have created a wildcard entry to the sub-domain area  in c-panel but when I add any prefix in the site name given the URL, it will redirect me to the main site like for example if I type abc.mysite.com then it will redirect me to mysite.com.

The site is in WordPress and I have tried a lot but couldn't reach to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**`This one possible using this plugin generate your subdomain as a your state name.`**

> Multisite Admin Bar Tweaks
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-admin-bar-tweaks/screenshots/
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Settings_Screen